# How do I uglify code when building Gatsby sites?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby, uglifyjs

I'm deploying with Gatsby and netlify, however I can see the complete pristine code in the Sources tab. I wish I could uglify this and make this a bit more obscure. Is there a way to uglify this `webpack` folder? Thanks!

[IMAGE: Code showing in webpack folder after build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQDAo.png)

PS: Even the official Gatsby website has the pristine code appearing, not sure if this is their design choice to make it more accessible or not.

### Same for reactjs.org:

[image: Reactjs.org Gatsby code]

### Same for Airbnb.io, with TODO comments:

[image: Airbnb.io Gatsby code]

Most sites you see in the [Gatsby Showcase](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/showcase/) expose their code in `webpack/./src`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom webpack config to disable source maps in production.

1 - Delete the `/public` folder, to make sure the previously created source maps are deleted

2- Add the following to your `gatsby-node.js` file:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, stage }) => {
  if (stage === 'build-javascript') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      devtool: false
    })
  }
};
```

---

Or, if you would rather use a gatsby plugin, you can use this:
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-no-sourcemaps/ which basically does the exact same thing.

(Have a look at what it does https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-no-sourcemaps/gatsby-node.js)

Make sure to delete the `/public` folder first, then run `gatsby build`.

To learn more:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-custom-webpack-config/
- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Comment: [This PR](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/4755) added an option to *disable* uglifying for production builds, which suggests Gatsb uglifies by default?